# LRU cache on hard drive python

Tags: python, caching, hard-drive, lru

I want to be able to decorate a function as you would do with [functools.lru_cache](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache), however, I want the results to be cached on the hard drive and not in memory. Looking around, I get a feeling this is a solved problem, and I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction (or at least give me a few more keywords to try googling)

I don't know if this will help or if it matters, but the function is computing images from unique filenames.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some code to get you started:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pickle
import hashlib
import os

class LRU_Cache:

    def __init__(self, directory, original_function, maxsize=10):
        self.directory = directory
        self.original_function = original_function
        self.maxsize = maxsize
        try:
            os.mkdir(directory)
        except OSError:
            pass

    def __call__(self, *args):
        filename = hashlib.sha1(pickle.dumps(args)).hexdigest()
        fullname = os.path.join(self.directory, filename)
        try:
            with open(fullname, 'rb') as f:
                value = pickle.load(f)
            Path(fullname).touch()
            return value
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
        value = self.original_function(*args)
        with open(fullname, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(value, f)
        filenames = os.listdir(self.directory)
        if len(filenames) <= self.maxsize:
            return
        fullnames = [os.path.join(self.directory, filename)
                     for filename in filenames]
        oldest = min(fullnames, key=lambda fn: os.stat(fn).st_mtime)
        os.remove(oldest)
```

It uses hashes the arguments to create a unique filename for each function call.  The function return value is pickled using that filename.

Cache hits unpickle the stored result and update the file modification time.

If the cache directory exceeds a target size, the oldest cache file is removed.

Use it like this:

```
def square(x):
    print('!')
    return x ** 2

sqr = LRU_Cache('square_cache', square, 10)
```

Now call *sqr* normally and results will be cached to disk.